# What is the best way to automatically auto scale AWS RDS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to autoscale AWS RDS automatically with scripts based on the metric monitoring.

Comment: Best way is using dynamoDB instead of RDS

Answer (score 4):

RDS doesn't really do this for Read-Write

Multi AZ Write-Read database copies are intended for failover from primary to secondary if there is an availability problem.  They don't address the problem of performance

Read replicas can be used to increase performance but they are read only

It might be possible to look at a load metric and use a Cloudwatch alarm to start an extra read replica.  Read replicas can be used via an ELB or NLB

But probably this isn't a good idea.  While an existing RDS is making a read replica, performance is degraded.  RDS read replicas are quite slow to come up and become available so it's unlikely to respond in a good way to transient demand

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I already have existed RDS database which I can't change. I need to find out a way to automatically scale it(vertically).

Comment: we had a problem with a hot table on our RDS database so I refactored the application to use AWS Elasticache Redis for the part of the app that used that table.  You'll have to find a work around too I guess.  Or pay a lot more for a larger instance

Answer (score 1):

You can make an API call to [Modify an RDS Instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ModifyInstance.MySQL.html), including changing the instance class.

Amazon RDS will provision a new instance of the desired class and will then re-point the Endpoint to the new instance. Existing connections will be terminated, but applications can reconnect and all the data will be there.

Rather than scaling the RDS instance, you could always consider a **caching layer**, such as Amazon ElastiCache that supports Redis and Memcached. Most applications are read-heavy, which is ideal for using a cache. This can significantly improve application performance without having to scale the database.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my application is write heavy application other wise I could have selected read replicas. I need some scripts to automatically check the RDS health and vertically autoscale the RDS based on the health.

Comment: You can certainly write scripts that use [Amazon CloudWatch metrics for Amazon RDS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/rds-metricscollected.html), which then call the API to modify the instance class.

Answer (score 0):

In simple, it can be possible with Aurora 5.7 DB RDS instances only, they provide an option to auto-scale based on cloud watch metric conditions i.e CPU utilization etc.

Comment: For Aurora we can automatically scale both size and memory, but I need to scale MySql instance, which can only be possible as vertical scaling for that vertical scaling I need automation scripts.